# Network Unreachable when uploading gpg public key

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to upload my gpg public key in order to deploy releases of my Maven artifacts to Maven Central. But when I run the following command:

```sh
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys E655AF47
```

I get the following error:

```sh
gpg: sending key E655AF47 to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver send failed: Network is unreachable
gpg: keyserver send failed: Network is unreachable
```

I am using gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.6 on MacBook.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Is it really `hkp` for the protocol?

Comment: I dunno, that's the output I get

Comment: Yeah, that's correct - I wasn't thinking of it the right way.  I'd try it again or restart your local network.  The server seems to be up so perhaps it was a temporary issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Is there a solution yet?

Comment: Same here with all 3 of the suggested servers.

Comment: From [Brian Richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19965855/brian-richardson): I'd like to add that this seems to be an issue with the Homebrew version of MacOS and not a networking issue. I've seen references to this same problem in multiple locations, and all of them are running the Homebrew version of GnuPG on MacOS. I have tried multiple keyservers, protocols, etc. and continue to receive this network error that appears to have nothing to do with the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like these servers not permit such mechanism anymore...

First, try to specify `https` protocol explicitly:

```bash
gpg --keyserver https://keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys E655AF47
```

If that is also not working, then you must upload it manually:

1. copy your public key:

```bash
gpg --armor --output public-key.gpg --export your@email.com
cat public-key.gpg | pbcopy
```

where `your@email.com` you can find with `gpg --list-signatures` command

2. go to https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/
3. Click `Submit Key` button
4. Paste your public key you've copied in 1st step with `pbcopy` command and submit it
5. Verify your submission like so:

https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0D6866D45122F4B762BBA078CA756566F2B91BC1&fingerprint=on&op=index

where `0D6866D45122F4B762BBA078CA756566F2B91BC1` your `keyid`, which you can also find with `gpg --list-signatures` command